# Programmatically create auto layout constraints with different constants for different size classes

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

If you use a Storyboard, you can add auto layout constraints to a view using Interface Builder, and you can very easily add different `constant` values for each size class you want. When you run the app and switch between size classes, the UI will automatically update and reposition to respect the correct `constant` value for the new size class.

My question is how can you obtain that same behavior programmatically?

When you create an `NSLayoutConstraint` you can't set different values for different size classes. I'm therefore thinking it would be a much more manual process. You'd have to create the constraints with the correct value for the current size class in `viewDidLoad` for example, then you'd have to use `willTransitionToTraitCollection` or maybe `updateConstraints` and detect the new size class, then change the `constant`s for all of the constraints that's appropriate for the new size class, then call `layoutIfNeeded` on the views that need to be repositioned. That would be a lot of code, made worse the more size classes you optimize for. Is there not an easier and/or more efficient way to obtain that behavior programmatically?

Note that this question isn't limited to auto layout constraints but rather any object that can have its properties' values change based on size class. For example, setting a `UILabel`'s font for different size classes.

Comment: I didn't find a clean solution. Had to make the optimizations in viewDidLoad and also after detecting size class changes. @SwiftArchitect

Comment: It's a pity Apple does not provide `addConstraint:forSizeClasses` or `activateConstraints:forSizeClasses`...

Comment: @SwiftArchitect Filing a radar now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Swift

You need to create different sets of `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Edit as per discussion below.

- [@Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1795356/joey): You have to handle size classes decision in both `viewDidLoad` (or similar) and `viewWillTransitionToSize`.
- Size class detection should be done inside the `animateAlongsideTransition` block, not before.

**Refactored code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let narrow = self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass 
                 == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact
    self.useNarrowConstraints(narrow)
}


override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize,
                                       withTransitionCoordinator
                                       coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({
        (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
            let narrow = self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass 
                         == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact
            self.useNarrowConstraints(narrow)
        })
        { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in 
        }
}
```

**Using Activation:**

```
func useNarrowConstraints(narrow: Bool) {
    if narrow {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints([self.fullWidthConstraint])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([self.halfWidthConstraint])
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints([self.halfWidthConstraint])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([self.fullWidthConstraint])
    }
}
```

Further details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35135695/218152).

**Using Substitution:**

```
func useNarrowConstraints(narrow: Bool) {
    view.removeConstraint(constraint)
    
    if narrow {
        constraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("format", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    } else {
        constraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("otherFormat", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    }
    view.addConstraint(constraint)
}
```

Comment: Where would this code go? You would surely have to remove all the constraints and re-add them with the right constants every time the size class changes.

Comment: Note that this method won't be called when the view is loaded. You'd need to duplicate that code in 'viewDidLoad'. Not as clean as I'd like, also it's terribly inefficient to remove constraints and readd them, but it'd work.

Comment: Correct on both accounts. Efficiency is a matter of perception ; better select a good algorithm rather than optimize a poor one. As such, my recommendation is to pick Storyboard over programatic solution if at all possible. **You can't beat 0 line of code**, and let the OS do the hard work.