# iOS Maintain constraint active state during rotation

Tags: ios, swift

I am animating a button to move from the center of a view to a corner and want to know how to make it stay there after I rotate the device. I mocked up a very simple app to show the issue. Here is the example storyboard:

[image: example storyboard]

The constraints are added to the appropriate IBOutletCollection in the ViewController and the Button action is linked to the IBAction sendToCorner in the example ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var centerConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
    @IBOutlet var cornerConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!

    @IBAction func sendToCorner() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(centerConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(cornerConstraints)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

The animation from the center to the corner works. However if I rotate the device after I send the button to the corner it returns to the center. My question is: how to permanently send the button to the corner with an animation? Or more generically, how to animate constraints and make the constraints active state permanent through device rotations.

Comment: I am using Xcode 9.0 and targeting iOS 11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep autolayout constraints active status on device rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130999/keep-autolayout-constraints-active-status-on-device-rotation)